# VBA macro to toolbar button in Open Office

Tags: vba, ms-word, openoffice-writer

I draw the short straw at work and got tasked with converting all our MS Word templates to OO.

All macros seems to work when the template is opened in OO but in MS Word we have a toolbar with the macros assigned to buttons in the toolbar.

My question is: Is there a way to add macros written in VBA to a toolbar in OO?

thanks!

Comment: You mean add VBA macros and *have them actually work* in OO? Nope.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, OpenOffice.org and Microsoft Office Makros don't go well together. I noticed you asked the [same question on the official OO.org Forums](http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=33877).